# I want to print the number which occur at least in their respective last cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

Given: I have `Level 1`, `Level 2`, `Level 3` columns

```
| Emp Id | Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 |
|--------|---------|---------|---------|
| 1      | E001    |         |         |
| 2      |         | E241    |         |
| 3      |         |         | E001    |
```

**Problem statement:** I want to make new column which will contain the last occuring column text.

**Expected OUTPUT:**

```
| Emp Id | Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 | Final |
|--------|---------|---------|---------|-------|
| 1      | E001    |         |         | E001  |
| 2      |         | E241    |         | E241  |
| 3      |         |         | E001    | E001  |
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: What have you tried? Tip, if you are only doing this with three levels then you can combine an IF() statement with an ISTEXT() statement but that is assuming each cell is empty.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose I have tried Nested **IF** As _for_ Level 1: `=IF(D2=0,C2,D2)` and Level 2: `=IF(C2=0,B2,IF(D2=0,C2,D2))` by making two column for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the blank cells do not contain non-printing characters or spaces, you can use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/LEN(B2:D2),B2:D2)
```

[image]